# How can I make svn:externals work with Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, svn, cordova

I am working on a phonegap project so I decided to use the phonegap project structure :

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/28103995/phonegap%20project%20structure

I am using SVN as SCM and it is located on an external server. My svn repository is available at this URL :

```
svn+ssh://myexternalserver.com:33999/
```

Xcode 4 don't support the port number in the url so I update my config .subversion file with this in the [tunnels] section :

```
sshfs = ssh -p 33999
```

So I created the repository in Xcode 4 with this URL :

```
svn:sshfs://myexternalserver.com
```

This is working fine.

Then I created this directory in the repo for my common/shared assets :

```
svn:sshfs://myexternalserver.com/trunk/myproject/
```

Then I created this directory in the repo for my iOS specific project :

```
svn:sshfs://myexternalserver.com/trunk/myproject-iOS/
```

In this folder I have this SVN property :

```
svn:externals www svn+ssh://myexternalserver.com:33999/trunk/myproject/
```

This svn:externals property is working fine with eclipse+subclipse (it create a www folder with the content of the "myproject" folder) but it dont work in Xcode 4.

When I checkout my project with Xcode the www folder is red with no folder icon.

I tried this SVN property :

```
svn:externals www svn+sshfs://myexternalserver.com/trunk/myproject/
```

But it fail with eclipse+subclipse with this error :

```
 Command completed abnormally.
     svn: Handshake failed, received: ''
```

What can I do to make it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix it by using relative path for the svn:externals property.

The SVN property is now :

```
svn:externals ../myproject/ www
```